# How do I overwrite the data on SQL rows while exporting from python using while loop?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a live stock quote Microsoft Excel spreadsheet that refreshes every minute. What I tried is to create a dataframe in python and then export it to SQL, and then data connection from excel to SQL table since `df.to_csv` doesn't work when the Excel file is open and I NEED the file to be open. I have created a `while` loop (ignore the value in minutes variable as it's random) and `df.to_sql` inside it. The issue is that, instead of overwriting the data, the loop creates new rows every time it is executed. How do I overwite the data in same existing rows? My code is below:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib


def get_current_price(symbol):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    todays_data = ticker.history(period='1d')
    return todays_data['Close'][0]


scrip = ['BLUESTARCO', 'AARTIIND', 'LUPIN','MFSL']
data = []
minutes = 0
while minutes < 340:
    for x in scrip:
        y = x
        x = x + '.NS'
        price = ('%.6s' % get_current_price(x))
        final = [y, price]
        data.append(final)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('symbol', 'CMP'))
    print(df['CMP'])
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SHRICOH;DATABASE=PythonImportTesting")
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
    df.to_sql('Live Ticker Yfinance', schema='dbo', con=engine,
          chunksize=200, method='multi', index=False, if_exists='replace')
    minutes += 1
```

This is how the table in SQL gets updated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPPjl.png

Comment: Your're appending in line `data.append(final)` if you don't want the data to be added in a new row instead change it to `data = final` or `df = pd.DataFrame(final, ...`

Comment: If I don't append, it only retuns the output of last data in scip().

Comment: I understood the issue, let me post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're never resetting the `data` list after getting new items, so you still have the old data and that's what you are storing in the SQL database.
The fix is to simply reset data to an empty list in the while loop

```
scrip = ['BLUESTARCO', 'AARTIIND', 'LUPIN','MFSL']
# Instead of here
minutes = 0
while minutes < 340:
    # Declare data here
    data = []
    for x in scrip:
        y = x
        x = x + '.NS'
        price = ('%.6s' % get_current_price(x))
        final = [y, price]
        data.append(final)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('symbol', 'CMP'))
    print(df['CMP'])
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SHRICOH;DATABASE=PythonImportTesting")
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
    df.to_sql('Live Ticker Yfinance', schema='dbo', con=engine,
          chunksize=200, method='multi', index=False, if_exists='replace')
    minutes += 1
```

Comment: You are right!!! I missed to look at that part, thank you!